# Laravel 6 - login with Phone or Email

Tags: laravel-6

I'm using Laravel 6 and want user can alternatively login by email or mobile.

My attempts so far:

- Migration is working fine.
- Registration is working fine

Login works fine one at a time either **email** or **mobile** with below changes in loginController.php.

```
public function username()
{
    return 'mobile'; // or email
}
```

and also 
**login.blade.php** for HTML forms from **email to mobile.**

I tried to validate both **email and phone** by **@error directive**, like @error('email') || @error('mobile') is-invalid @enderror but no action after submit. below is the example

```
<input id="user_login" type="text" class="form-control @error('email') || @error('mobile') is-invalid @enderror" name="user_login" value="{{ old('user_login') }}" required autocomplete="user_login" autofocus>

                            @error('user_login')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
```

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Could you add a snippet of your attempt?

Comment: thanks for the help, I have update my question, please check.

Comment: @MaartenDev any thought about above explanation?

Answer (score 0):

change User migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('username')->unique()->nullable();
        $table->string('mobile_number')->unique()->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

change User model:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password', 'mobile_number'
];
```

in `app\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController.php` change:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'mobile_number' => $data['mobile_number'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

then change your register and login views and add a field to get `mobile_number`

Comment: Thanks for the help, these attempts were already done please recheck my question, I have updated it.

Answer (score 0):

The provided blade template contains incorrect blade syntax that gets transformed to invalid php(the `||` is converted to plain text instead of the `OR` operation).

Checkout the resulting php below:
[image: incorrect php]

This can be fixed by using the `@error` and `enderror` twice:

```
<form action="{{ route('test.store') }}" method="post">
    <input id="user_login" type="text" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror @error('mobile') is-invalid @enderror" name="user_login" value="{{ old('user_login') }}" required autocomplete="user_login" autofocus>

    @error('user_login')
```

To add an additional field for authenticating the following can be used:

> resources/auth/login.blade.php

```
   <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="phone" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Phone') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="phone" type="text" class="form-control @error('phone') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('phone') }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>

                                @error('phone')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" autocomplete="email" autofocus>

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

> app/Http/Auth/LoginController.php

Overriding the `username()` method to use phone if provided and email as fallback.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function username()
    {
        return request()->has('phone') ? 'phone' : 'email';
    }
}
```

> or with a single field:

```
  <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="user_identifier" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address/Phone') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="user_identifier" type="text" class="form-control @error('user_identifier') is-invalid @enderror" name="user_identifier" value="{{ old('user_identifier') }}" autofocus>

                                @error('user_identifier')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

and the associated `LoginController` method:

```
    public function username()
    {
        $identifier = request()->get('user_identifier');

        if(filter_var($identifier, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
            return 'email';
        }

        return 'phone';
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this, to make it work do you suggest anything in this code: return 'phone'; // or email

Comment: that seems fine but be sure to check if phone numbers provided by the user are unique. Does the code work with the updated blade setup? @BalramSharma

Comment: No luck, just the page gets refresh any thoughts?

Comment: What does your `<form>` look like @BalramSharma? What action does it have?

Comment: It is a simple Laravel auth form i have installed, by default it accepts email login and I'm trying to login by mobile as well.

Comment: Is the phone an alternative to email or a replacement? @BalramSharma

Comment: trying to make phone alternative

Comment: Thanks really appreciated, the above code has two different fields can't we combine it to one like facebook does (E-Mail / Mobile) either one

Comment: It can be combined for sure, checkout the updated example @BalramSharma

Comment: Does above code really works for you? because it didn't here, anything did I miss?

Comment: What part does not work? @BalramSharma Did you copy the form-group into the form and add the method to the LoginController?

Comment: I replaced HTML and public function username() that you provided above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206742/discussion-between-maartendev-and-balram-sharma).